При клике на placemark отображать слева внизу "Как добраться" без balloon
Есть много placemark меток. И когда я нажимаю на одну из них надпись в левом нижнем углу "Открыть в Яндекс Картах" не меняется на "Как добраться". Как сделать чтобы именно при клике на placemark сменить "Как добраться" чтобы появлялась возможность сразу построить маршрут, сейчас это работает только если на placemark создать balloon, но мне он не нужен. Буду признателен за помощь



Кнопка «Открыть в Яндекс Картах» меняется на «Как добраться», когда в видимой области карты остаётся только одна метка.
Потому возможные варианты с нашей собственной кнопкой:

удалять/скрывать лишние кнопки после клика с последующим восстановлением их, например, при клике на карту, если нужно
масштабировать карту к метке, чтобы прочие уходили из зоны видимости.

Для второго варианта код может выглядеть так:
myMap.geoObjects.events.add('click', function (e) {
  var target = e.get('target');
  var coords = target.geometry.getCoordinates();    
  myMap.setCenter(coords, 16);
});

Если оба варианта не подходят нужно отключить эту кнопку целиком опцией suppressMapOpenBlock. А дальше добавить собственную, клик по которой должен будет открывать ссылку перехода в Карту с координатами нажатой метки по нашей схеме.
